# Error connecting to Windows Active Directory via LDAP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap

I installed a Windows Server 2012 and set an Active Directory Service (AD) and a domain.

I can add Windows 7 workstations to that domain and login with users that are in the AD.

I want to connect to the AD through LDAP for use AD users login in some web application. The application is developed in asp.net MVC5. I use the following connection:

```
LDAP://servername.domain.local:389/DC=domain,DC=local
```

But always get the error:

> Unable to establish secure connection with the server - The server is not operational.

I also try to connect to AD using LDAP in the Internet Explorer providing this connection:

```
LDAP://servername.domain.local:389
```

But again I get an error:

> An error occurred while performing the search. Your computer, your Internet service provider, or the specified directory service may be disconnected. Check your connections and try again. Operations Error.

Is there any configurations that I miss in order to connect Windows Active Directory using LDAP protocol? Is any other way to test my connection?

Comment: What if you try the *server-less* binding: `LDAP://DC=domain,DC=local` - does that work?

Comment: No. If I try that in IE browser I get this error message: "The specified directory service could not be reached. The service may be temporarily unavailable or the server name may be incorrect."